# How do i decode this string? \xc3\x99\xc3\xa9\xc2\x87-B[x\xc2

Tags: encryption, redis, ascii, decode, utf8-decode

This is what I need to decode

```
\xc3\x99\xc3\x99\xc3\xa9\xc2\x87-B[x\xc2\x99\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa6\x14Ez\xc2\xab
```

it is generated by `String.fromCharCode(arrayPw[i]);`
but i don't understand how to decode it :(

Please help

Comment: Without knowledge of the encryption system and key, the ciphertext could conceivably be decrypted to *literally anything*. This is not a useful question for this site.

Answer (score 3):

**Python:**

```
data = "\xc3\x99\xc3\x99\xc3\xa9\xc2\x87-B[x\xc2\x99\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa6\x14Ez\xc2\xab"
udata = data.decode("utf-8")
asciidata = udata.encode("ascii","ignore")
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

Otherwise do more research about decoding UTF-8.

https://gist.github.com/chrisveness/bcb00eb717e6382c5608

There's also an online UTF-8 decoder/encoder:

https://mothereff.in/utf-8

**HINT:** `ÙÙé-B[x¾æEz«`

Comment: How do i do this? Like is this javascript?

Comment: The output is supposed to be in plain text:(

Comment: The data decoded is `ÙÙé-B[x¾æEz«`... well... what is it?

Comment: @Raptor If only we knew :-)

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815136/5902698

You load a dataset and you have some strange characters.
Exemple :

> 'æˆ´æ£®ç¾Žå�‘é€\xa0åž‹å™¨å®Œæ•´ç‰ˆå¥—è£…Dyson Airwrap
> HS01ï¼ˆé“œé‡‘è‰²ç¤¼ç›’ç‰ˆï¼‰'

In my case, I know that the strange characters are chineses. So I can figure that the one who send me the data have encode it in utf-8 but should do it in 'ISO-8859-1'.

So first step, I had encoded the string, then I decode with utf-8.
so my lines are :

```py
_encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
_my_str.encode(_encoding, 'ignore').decode("utf-8", 'ignore')
```

Then my output is :

> "'森Dyson Airwrap HS01礼'"

This works for me, but I guess that I do not really well understood under the hood. So feel free to tell me if you have further information.

Bonus. I'll try to detect when the str is in the first strange format because some of my entries are in chinese but others are in english

EDIT : The Bonus is useless. I Just use lamba on ma column to encode and decode without care about format. So I changed the encoding after loading the dataframe

```py
_encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
_decoding = "utf-8"
df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : x.encode(_encoding, 'ignore').decode(_decoding , 'ignore'))
```