# Pandas dataframe imports and renders incorrectly and causes UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import an csv that contains Chinese characters.

this command is to download the csv file

```
!wget -O wm.csv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hierarchyJK/compare-LIBSVM-with-Linear-and-Gassian-Kernel/master/%E8%A5%BF%E7%93%9C3.0.csv
```

The repository is not mine, so I am not sure if it is encoded the right way.

what I can be sure is that it [renders](https://github.com/hierarchyJK/compare-LIBSVM-with-Linear-and-Gassian-Kernel/blob/master/%E8%A5%BF%E7%93%9C3.0.csv) correctly.

this code

```
pd.read_csv('wm.csv',encoding = 'utf-8')
```

causes this Error

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 0: invalid start byte

I've searched this error, didn't find appropriate rca and solution.

this code executed properly

```
pd.read_csv('wm.csv',encoding = 'cp1252')
```

but renders the garbled

[image]

the system renders Chinese characters correctly.

[image]

with python open command

```
with open('wm.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
        break
```

this code renders something garbled without any warning or error.

```
±àºÅ,É«Ôó,¸ùµÙ,ÇÃÉù,ÎÆÀí,Æê²¿,´¥¸Ð,ÃÜ¶È,º¬ÌÇÂÊ,ºÃ¹Ï,Ðò¹ØÏµ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is 'GB18030'. I found this by opening the file in a text editor and checking the suggested encoding. Github actually also shows you the encoding when you go to the github link and click on edit file

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `encoding="GBK"`. Hope this will help.

```
df = pd.read_csv('wm.csv', encoding="GBK")
```

More details check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308065/how-to-display-chinese-characters-inside-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with all of the standard encodings. Latin_1 have worked well for me when I have had issues, but in your case you can try utf_16_be. Good Luck.!

[Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)